# Add view programatically in Android with a pre defined layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I constantly find myself adding views programmatically and then one by one changing some of it's attributes. This isn't a big deal until I have to go and change something like it's height or width, because then I have to do a dpi calculation. Is there anyway to turn this:

```
TextView view = new TextView(activity);
view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
view.setText(names[position]);
view.setTextColor(myColor);
```

To this:

```
TextView view = new TextView(activity);
view.setLayout(R.layout.sample);
```

I feel like there must be a way, but when I search online, I can't think of a word to describe what the view is doing to the layout. That's why I've chose "pre defined layout" added to a view. Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can always inflate a layout file and then simply add the inflated view

Comment: Inflate a layout? And I can attach it to the view?!

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly, but sort of. You can programmatically inflate a view from an XML layout:

```
TextView view = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sample, parentViewGroup);
```

Comment: This answer can be improved by passing `parentViewGroup` as the second argument to the `inflate()` call, instead of `null`. If you don't pass a view container then any layout attributes of the inflated view will be ignored!

Comment: Good point. Not sure why I didn't put it there in the first place. Edited, thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to enter `parentViewGroup` but I'm getting `parentViewGroup cannot be resolved to a variable`.

Comment: @EGHDK yeah, `parentViewGroup` is just a generic variable I made up to represent the parent `ViewGroup`. This is often the `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` that you want your `TextView` to be in. If you want your `TextView` as the root view, then just substitute `null` for `parentViewGroup`.

Comment: What if I don't want to place it anywhere on that line? On my next line can I do ViewGroup.addView(view)?

Comment: Yes, you can do what I had before. Pass in `null` initially, then later on when you're ready you can do `viewGroup.addView(view)`. Just note Alex's warning above.

Comment: So does null place it in the root view? Or does it not place it anywhere at all until you tell it?

Comment: Take a look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29). If you pass in `null` it **is** the root view. However, that just means it's the root view of the view hierarchy, it doesn't mean that it's part of *your activity's* view hierarchy. It won't be unless you call [`setContentView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29) on it.